# How to serve static files to AWS when deploying Django app (`python manage.py collectstatic` didn't work)?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework

Yesterday, I created this post: [DjangoRestFramework browsable api looks different locally vs when deployed on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405552/djangorestframework-browsable-api-looks-different-locally-vs-when-deployed-on-se)

Basically, when I did `python manage.py runserver`, this showed up: [image: local]

But after I deployed it to AWS (`eb deploy`), this is what I see when I access the site: [image: on deploy]

The answer to the post above mentioned that it is because my static files were missing. So I searched how to deploy static files on AWS and came across this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-update-app

Under the "Create a Site Administrator" section, it mentions that in order to serve static files, I must first define `STATIC_ROOT` in `settings.py` (so I did: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "ebdjangoapp/static/")`) and then I did `eb deploy`. However, the site still looks the same as the 2nd image (without static files). I then tried doing `python manage.py collectstatic` (this created the static folder with the `rest_framework` directory inside it, containing the `css` files etc.) and then did `eb deploy` again but the site stil looks the same as the 2nd image.

How come the static files still aren't showing up?

Note, I searched around and came across this post: [Django app deployment not loading static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416057/django-app-deployment-not-loading-static-files) and the answer says:

"You then need to serve `settings.STATIC_ROOT` at `settings.STATIC_URL` via your web server of choice, very commonly nginx as a reverse proxy behind your Apache-mod_wsgi app server."

But I have no idea how web servers (nginx, reverse proxy, Apache-mod_wsgi) works. I have a Django app I run locally with `python manage.py runserver`, and I have AWS elastic beanstalk. I deploy my Django app to AWS by doing `eb deploy`. What steps do I need to take in order for the static files to appear on deployment (assuming I don't know how to configure nginx, reverse proxy etc.).?

Comment: Are you running ``python manage.py collectstatic`` at any time?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, I did it right before I did `eb deploy`. (Basically, I did it locally, and all the files got put in the static folder, then I deployed it).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is definitive guide about deploying a django app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk from RealPython - [here it is](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).
It has whole section about static files and how to configure it with eb and you don't need to know anything about nginx/apache etc.

Basically you should define `container_commands` in your eb config, these commands will be executed after application deploy is finished. For example `migrate` and `collectstatic`, so this is an example of such section in eb config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python iotd/manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python iotd/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "iotd.settings"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/iotd:$PYTHONPATH"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: iotd/iotd/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "www/static/"
```

Pay attention to `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles` part.
And also you should define this part in your django settings file:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "www", "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I copied this example almost entirely from article above, you should really check it, it's awesome.

UPD: how to debug missing staticfiles.
I usually do this (it involves sshing to your eb instance):

1. Make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.
2. Check in browser console url to missing file e.g.
   `/static/js/somefile.js`
3. Make sure in my django settings `STATIC_URL` is the same e.g. `/static/`.
4. Check actual value in `STATIC_ROOT` and check that this folder actually contains your static files in production server.
5. Check that my eb config is pointing to correct folder (under your `option_settings` section in config)

Also you can try to collect static into `/static` dir on your production server (it's where eb looks for them by default). If all of a sudden it starts working - it means that your setting failed to override default one and you should check where else it was defined.

I hope these steps will help you to find right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So I edited `settings.py` so that `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` is what you mentioned. I then created a file called `02_python.config` inside the `.ebextensions` folder and copy pasted exactly what you have posted here. I change `iotd` to `ebdjango` (name of my project.. my app name is `ebdjangoapp`).  I then changed `python ebjango/manage.py collectstatic --noinput` to `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` (since the python path leads to `ebdjango` already). But it still doesn't work (server still looks like the 2nd image I posted). Any idea how to debug this issue?

Comment: Answer updated with possible debugging steps, hope it'll help.

Comment: The update helped a lot! Now, when I let `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` and not mention `staticfiles` in my `option_settings` config file, it works (default location, as you mentioned)! When I give an absolute or relative path to `"aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles"` in `option_settings`, it works as well. But when I change `STATIC_ROOT` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "www", "static")` and do `"/static/": "www/static/"` in my `option_settings`, it gives a 404 for static files. When I let it equal `"/static/": "../www/static/"`, it gives a 403 for static.

Comment: I'll mark you're answer as correct when the bounty is about to finish, but for now, any idea why it gives a 403 when I let `STATIC_ROOT` equal `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "www", "static")`? (it does create a `ebdjango/../www/static/` folder which has the `rest_framework` staticfiles).

Comment: 403 means that some internal web server doesn't have access to this folder. Easiest way to fix it is give this access, but you have to know actual username of this server and it's not convenient. By the way, I consider you use eb instance for static file only as the matter of initial tutorial. Next step would be use S3 bucket for this :)

Comment: Note: When using Amazon Linux 2, the namespace is aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles. See [the ELB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentproxystaticfiles).

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.

Remove any staticfiles directives from `.config` files. Find *Static Files* section under the Software Configuration. The left column is each of your `/static/` url. The right is your static folder relative to **your parent directory**.

[image]

Make sure your `STATIC_ROOT` setting matches the value on the right. Don't forget the trailing `/`.

Pasting my settings anyway.

```
 STATIC_URL = '/static/'
 STATICFILES_DIRS = ('assets',)
 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'www', 'static')
```

And this is what my folder structure looks like relative to the settings files

```
project/
├── __init__.py
├── settings
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── local.py
│   ├── production.py
```

`wsgi.py`, `urls.py` are located in `project` folder. `www` folder is one level above `project` folder.

Hope this saves your Sunday at least.

Comment: Hello Manu, I am trying to implement your solution but I am unable to find the Static files section under the software configuration. How did you enable the virtual paths?

Comment: Your answer is good but may not be clear enough. 1. STATIC_ROOT is your target directory, when collectstatic will pull found static files. I recommend giving a name like 'static_build' for this value. 2. Run collect static locally and commit all files in static_build to your source tree. 3. Set STATIC FILES value per Virtual Path in AWS or via .ebextensions/django.config. This requires less configuration than trying to configure the server to run collectstatic each time it deploys.