# Static files configuration in AWS not working

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-config

I currently have an multi-docker container application (nginx, postgres RDS, Django) running on Elastic BeanStalk and I am able to use it but the static files (CSS files and JS scripts) are not loaded. This is my current configuration:

**nginx setup file**

```
 user nginx;
 worker_processes 1;

 events {
   worker_connections 1024;
 }

http {
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
client_max_body_size 100M;

server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    server_name mydashboard.com;

    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout info;

    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/media/;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8888; 
        proxy_set_header host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }
}
```

**.ebextensions (folder)**

**django.config (file)**

```
 option_settings:
     "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "mydashboard.settings"
    "ALLOWED_HOSTS": ".elasticbeanstalk.com"
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
     WSGIPath: mydashboard/mydashboard/wsgi.py
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "www/static/"
```

**settings.py**

```
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),)
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "www", "static")
  STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
  MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

If I remove the folder `.ebextensions` folder and load the app, it will work without displaying the static files but if I add the folder with the `django.conf` file the app won't deploy and I will encounter the error: `Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles', OptionName: '/static/'): Unknown configuration setting.`

In one post I found ([Serving static files in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462880/how-to-serve-static-files-to-aws-when-deploying-django-app-python-manage-py-co/42501995)) it is mentioned that all staticfiles directives from .config files should be removed and under the Software Configuration I should configure the static files under the Static File section, however, this Static File section is not even displayed. What code am I missing for displaying the static files? Thanks in advance for your suggestions and answers.

Comment: Check `django.config` file indentation so it is as in examples.

Answer (score 7):

There is new settings for EBS

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: mysite.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
container_commands:
  01_collectstatic:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, thanks. @abautista please consider marking this as an accepted answer if it resolved your problem