# Django Elastic Beanstalk Static Configuration not working

Tags: django, configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-staticfiles, ebextensions

I'm trying to deploy a Django application on Elastic Beanstalk, and had problems with my css files in the static folder generated by `python3 manage.py collectstatic` being read by my html templates.

I digged deeper, and turns out when I SSH into the EC2 instance that is hosting my application, the file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_static.conf` contains

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/app/current/static;
    access_log off;
}
```

My application only works when I manually change this file to contain

```
location /static/ {
    alias /var/app/current/static/;
    access_log off;
}
```

The only change here is that I added a trailing slash at the end of the alias. I looked this up more, and was recommended that I create a `01_static.config` file in the `.ebextensions` directory within the root directory, which I did and populated with the following:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_static.conf":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      alias /var/app/current/static/;
```

However, this doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone have solutions as to how I can add the trailing slash without manually SSHing into an EC2 instance on every deployment? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also generate static files with container commands.  Try the config files below in ebextensions.

```
container_commands:   01_collectstatic:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
    leader_only: true 
option_settings:   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: YOURAPP.settings
```

--EDIT--
My bad I didn't understand your question.  You can make custom settings for nginx using extension.

Try the following config files if you are using AL2.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /static: static
```

Answer from here [Static files configuration in AWS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379814/static-files-configuration-in-aws-not-working)  has this setting combined with my previous answer.

If that doesn't workout, you can also try to make a custom settings for nginx.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html.

Make a custom config files under .platform/nginx/conf.d/custom.config

Comment: I created a file called container-commands.config under .ebextensions and filled it with the code you provided (with proper indentation), and it's still not working as intended. Is there any way I can use container commands to change the content in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_static.conf?

Comment: In your logs, search for "01_collectstatic" in "cfn-init-cmd.log" and "cfn-init.log".  They should show you whether the command was actually executed or not, and the result if executed

Comment: It seems like the container command did run, with the output "0 static files copied to '/var/app/staging/static', 164 unmodified". I'm still confused on how this would help in modifying the alias in /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_static.conf.

Comment: Thank you for your edit! It's all working now thanks to you!