# Create react app + Django deployment Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: django, web-deployment, create-react-app, django-deployment

I've been trying to deploy an app to pythonanywhere but the page is just blank, because **main.6f259c1b.js** file throws error`

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

`
I've been following the instuctions on this article https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/create-react-app-and-django/624/ and this https://www.techiediaries.com/create-react-app-django/
both articles suggest to create a view with following content

```
class FrontendAppView(View):
    """
    Serves the compiled frontend entry point (only works if you have run `yarn
    run build`).
    """

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(settings.REACT_APP_DIR, 'build', 'index.html')) as f:
                return HttpResponse(f.read())
        except FileNotFoundError:
            logging.exception('Production build of app not found')
            return HttpResponse(
                """
                This URL is only used when you have built the production
                version of the app. Visit http://localhost:3000/ instead, or
                run `yarn run build` to test the production version.
                """,
                status=501,
            )
```

and in app website/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', FrontendAppView.as_view())
]
```

Those instructions don't work for me. It's something that related to **pushState routing, react-routing**, I don't know. My app works ok in development server in **localhost:3000**, it only seen in **pythonanywhere** and **local apache server with mod_wsgi**.
This is my config of local apache(from Django documentation):

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/projects/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /home/user/.virtualenvs/myproject
WSGIPythonPath home/user/projects/myproject/

<Directory /home/user/projects/myproject/myproject>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

This is root

```
DocumentRoot "/srv/http"
```

Part of my settings

```
REACT_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(REACT_APP_DIR, 'build', 'static')
]
```

All software are latest release.
Maybe this comment solves my problem, I just don't understand it. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1812#issuecomment-286511320

This is my localhost screenshot
[image: localhost screenshot]

My project directory structure

```
├── api_v0
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── myproject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── local.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── frontend
│   ├── build
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── public
│   ├── README.md
│   └── src
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── admin
│   ├── css
│   ├── js
│   ├── media
│   └── rest_framework
└── website
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── management
    ├── middleware.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── __pycache__
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

Comment: Jesus, it's always helps when you ask other people then you find the solution yourself it's stange. This answer gave me the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/23416586/7945930  It happens that I read the serving files part of Django docs, but had chosen the first simple config, which is not complete. Now I have to figure out how this supposed to work on pythonanywhere

Comment: can you just click into main.6f259c1b.js and see where the syntax error is?

Comment: @conrad it looks like the error has gone don't know whether it's configuring apache solved this or changing the react jsx files.

Comment: probably the latter

Answer (score 0):

Review the styles referenced on the page and make sure that all the CSS files are referenced on the page using a `<link>` tag and not a `<script>` tag.

[reference](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-error-message-thrown-in-the-layoutsbasics-css#:%7E:text=Uncaught%20SyntaxError%3A%20Unexpected%20token%20.,-Defect%2FEnhancement%20Number&text=In%20general%20this%20issue%20occurs,of%20a%20tag.)

also there are nginx adubting , you can do it for request your site adminstator help